# Is there a global shortage of IP addresses or not?

Tags: ip, ipv6, ipv4

This is bugging me a bit, so would like some help.  Here's some data I've gathered:

Apparently, an IPv4 address can range from 0.0.0.0 through to 255.255.255.255, providing up to 4,294,967,296 unique IPv4 addresses, although according to this article there are only 3.7 billion usable addresses: [https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=348253&seqNum=7#:~:text=IPv4%20uses%2032-bit%20IP,than%20the%20theoretical%20maximum%20number](https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=348253&seqNum=7#:%7E:text=IPv4%20uses%2032-bit%20IP,than%20the%20theoretical%20maximum%20number).

[image]

This website: https://www.statista.com/statistics/617136/digital-population-worldwide/ - says that almost 4.57 billion people were active internet users as of July 2020.  So all these users are allocated IP addresses on their handhelds and / or PC's, as well as other devices included in the IOT, from security cameras to servers, from Raspberry Pi's to cluster nodes.

Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion - says that the IPv4 addresses were exhausted back in 2011, and also indicates that some IOT devices may use IPv6 inherently.

The APNIC details are helpful: https://www.apnic.net/manage-ip/ipv4-exhaustion/ - where they define the running out of IPv4 as the free pool running out, and that businesses would have reserved IP's that they can still hand out.  The charts on this page say that today, only 0.25% IP addresses are left.  I understand this to mean that some IP addresses were reclaimed successfully as described in the Wikipedia article.

[image]

What made me look into this was that I recently migrated my websites from Siteground to Dreamhost.  Siteground use cPanel, meaning each user only gets a single IP address allocated to them, and cPanel works out where all the different subdomains / add-on domains end up.  Dreamhost, however, allocates 2 IP addresses for each domain, subdomain, and add-on domain that is hosted with them, which seemed odd as I've heard a lot about how scarce IPv4 addresses are.  I've got about 10 websites with them so 20 IP addresses as opposed to just the one I had with Siteground.

So I'm confused as to whether IPv4 addresses are going to run out or not.

- I've never used an IPv6 address in my life.
- Dreamhost are giving away IPv4 addresses as if they can't get rid of them fast enough.
- The world population is constantly growing, as is the amount of internet hosts connected to the internet.
- Wikipedia says that we ran out of IPv4 in 2011, yet I can still get new ones. (Because Dreamhost already owns them?)
- There's a lot of sources on the internet discussing the shortage, and the move to IPv6.

What's going on here?

- Is there any way to tell how many delegated IP's are actually in use?
- Why would Dreamhost or anyone else give away so many IP's if they're as valuable as they seem?
- How close are we to using IPv6 globally and will IPv4 be deprecated when it's globally in use?
- According to this question https://superuser.com/questions/768067/why-are-we-still-stuck-on-ipv4-when-we-are-ipv6-ready#768086 IPv6 and IPv4 are not cross compatible so how does the implementation of IPv6 help the IPv4 situation?
- If we're so close to running out, what is actually being done about it - surely it won't be long before this happens?
- And furthermore, what on earth would actually happen if we finally run out of IPv4 completely?  Would it cause security issues or prevent people accessing the internet?

Sorry for all the questions but none of this seems to make logical sense!

Comment: See the answers to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/53935/8499).

Comment: What's being done about it? Most of us are moving to IPv6 as fast as possible. Which is far slower than we would like, for a variety of reasons that have been discussed in depth elsewhere. Unfortunately this post is way too broad; you'll probably need books to answer all of these questions.

Comment: https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html#tab=per-country-ipv6-adoption

Comment: The original distribution channels for IPv4 addresses are depleted. Technologies like NAT64 lower the dependency on IPv4 addresses. The prices in the transfer market are still going up. But there are still plenty of organisations willing to pay those prices. All this makes the IPv4 internet more and more an exclusive club, which is the main reason deploying IPv6 is so important.

Answer (score 3):

No, DreamHost is not giving you 2 IPv4 address just for fun. Notice their [Unique IP](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216109647-Unique-IP-overview) is a separate option with a cost. You are sharing non-unique IPs, possibly with thousands of other sites. They can't possibly host [a million web sites](https://www.dreamhost.com/company/) on a [hundred thousand IPs](https://bgp.he.net/AS26347#_prefixes) unless some shared. Even that is relatively rich because they were an early adopter. A new hosting provider starting today can't get v4 from ARIN anymore.

Bad analogy time. IPv4 addresses are a "product" the manufacturer "stopped making" (IANA ran out). The regional "warehouses" (RIR pools) are also out of stock. And you can only get the "vendor" to talk to you about a plan to upgrade (the last slivers are reserved for IPv6 transition).

You have not noticed the impact of the exhaustion because of enormous effort by network operators to conserve ever smaller and fragmented subnets. Named based virtual hosts, NATs, transfers on the resale market.  It is astonishing the internet still works with this technical debt.

IPv6 is a solution you can implement today. It has the address space to meet global needs, like the next 10 billion IP devices. It is not feasible to make v6 compatible with v4, a 32 bit field does not fit a 128 bit value. Because getting the entire planet to do a cutover date seems very unlikely, we are in a transition period. For the foreseeable future, v6 will be the network, and v4 will be a legacy service if needed.

Compare to the transition of telephones from [local named exchanges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_exchange_names) to national all number plans. That took a few decades, but now you can direct dial almost anywhere in the world. Eventually, IPv4 will seem as quaint as a 4 digit phone number.

Comment: Thanks John, lot of downvotes on my question but no one has given me any criticism on how to make it better so really appreciate the answer.

Comment: This is well documented and has been many years in the making. My answer is partly to get you to see that your hosting provider doesn't actually have that many IPv4 addresses. And also to see the exhaustion procedures put in place by the assigning authorities and network operators.